# Install boost binaries non-interactively

Tags: c++, boost

Is there any way of installing the [Boost pre-compiled binaries](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/) non-interactively from the command line?

Purpose is for automation of installing Boost onto Windows machines, but compiling from source takes a really long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup executables have command line switches `/SP-`, `/SILENT`, `/VERYSILENT`, that disable installation messages.

`/NOCANCEL` is also worthy to note.

Run them with `/?` to get full list of supported options.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
boost_1_72_0-msvc-14.2-64.exe /sp- /silent /suppressmsgboxes /norestart
```

if you need full automation you can suppress window mode with `/verysilent` and wait for process to finish by piping it into `more`

```
C:/path/to/boost_1_72_0-msvc-14.2-64.exe /sp- /verysilent /suppressmsgboxes /norestart | more
```